# Handle static file (css, js, img) in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a React app and I'm using a template for this app. This is my react app's folder structure:

```
|app
|-client
|---assets
|---component
|-node_modules
|-server
|---index.html
|---index.js
```

In my `server/index.html` there are many static files such as css, js and img.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/img/logo-fav.png">
    <title>Loyalty Multipolar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/lib/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/lib/material-design-icons/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="be-wrapper" id="root">

    </div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>

  <script src="assets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/lib/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      Plugins.init();
    });

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to handle those files in a React app? Meanwhile in a Node JS app we use this to handle static files:

```
app.use('/assets',express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

the static file isn't loaded and not found if i type eg: 
`localhost:3000/assets/js/jquery`, the file is not available

and this is my `server/index.js` file:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config.dev';

let app = express();
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
  hot: true,
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  noInfo: true,
}));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.use('/assets',express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));


app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../index.html'));
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running port 3000'));
```

Thank you.

Comment: What needs to be handled here?

Comment: in this example , the static file isn't loaded and not found if i type eg: localhost:3000/assets/js/jquery, the file is not available

Comment: This has nothing to do with React but rather your server config.

Comment: i did add app.use('/assets',express.static(__dirname + '/assets')); in my server/index.js

Comment: Make sure `__dirname` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: i will put my server/index.js in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put static files as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Container Components Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/bootstrap.theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>
<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: https://github.com/johibkhan2/react-sample-app/blob/master/index.html

Comment: i did but it doesn't work , for example i want to add `jquery.js` plugin but it is not available ,is there any wrong code in my `server/index.js` file

Comment: /** try this
 * Anything in assets can be accessed statically without
 * this express router getting involved
 */

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets'), {
  dotfiles: 'ignore',
  index: false
}))

Comment: it works thank you, what is different with my static code

Comment: seems slash was creating an issue